# AWS Pinpoint journey, segments attributes mismatch with current values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I have a few dynamic segments created, base on a "master" segment that is imported from a CSV file located in an S3 bucket. This segment "master" segment is updated every 24 hours and reuploaded to S3, we also have a boto3 API create_import_job that updates this segment.

I have confirm an segments and dynamic segments are updated accordingly.

The problem I am having is when using Journeys, when I create a journey and this journey is linked to a segment. (the journey is created with refresh every hour and update on segment update to true). The journey doesnt update the endpoints values/attributes. For instance if endpoints leaves the segment they are still present in the journey and also if the endpoint started a journey with an attribute of user.attribute.amount = 1000, if I update the segment and change this attribute value to 500. The journey send an email/SMS with 1000, not 500. And if i export the segment, then export shows me the correct value of 500.

It looks like the journey is stuck with all the original values and never refreshed despite of having the refresh 1hour and update on segment update.

Is there something that I am missing in the configuration?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?